# Create a .aar file from my react-native project and use it in other project?

Tags: react-native

is it possible? does .aar contain the javascript code what i have written for screens and components? will i be able to impost specific component from .aar in my new project?

Tried couple of things like this [text](https://medium.com/@jyubinpatel/make-reactnative-module-as-a-library-and-how-its-used-into-android-native-application-35b13f65ac7c) but not able to generate .aar